# How to debug project with makefile

Tags: c, debugging, makefile, emacs, gdb

I'm a newbie both in makefiles and in projects using multiple files. What I'm working on now has one main.c and two user libraries. Here's the makefile:

```
CC = gcc
OBJECTS = main.o path.o util.o

9_1 : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJECTS) -o 9_1

main.o : main.c path.h util.h
    $(CC) -g -c main.c path.h util.h
path.o : path.c path.h util.h
    $(CC) -g -c path.c path.h util.h
util.o : util.c util.h
    $(CC) -g -c util.c util.h

.PHONY : clean
clean : 
    rm $(OBJECTS)
```

I'd like to be able to debug this project in Emacs (using the multiple-windows variable) however when I run `gdb -i=mi 9_1` (the default option) and try to add breakpoints in main.c it doesn't let me. Specifically: I run `b main.c:25` and I get

```
No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command.
Breakpoint 1 (main.c:25) pending
```

What should I do?

Comment: have you cleaned your project? because if the -g option has been added _after_ the compilation then make doesn't rebuild.

Comment: btw `$(CC) -g -c main.c path.h util.h` => `$(CC) -g -c main.c` don't compile the header files...

Comment: what do you mean by cleaning my project?

Comment: `make clean` then build again.

Comment: note that you get all those upvotes because as opposed to most newbies here you're actually _attempting_ to debug your code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened because

- you already built your objects/executable without the `-g` flag
- you added the `-g` flag *afterwards*

Adding an option in the makefile doesn't automatically trigger a recompilation. Since you have a `clean` target, just do

```
make clean
make
```

and the objects are rebuilt with the `-g` option: executable is produced with symbols now. Happy debugging.

Aside: don't pass header files to the `gcc` command. They're useful so `make` knows the dependencies (in the line above) but not when building the object from the `.c` file. Doing so creates useless `.o` files.